# Designing Android App UI for Tab and mobile

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, tabletools

I am working on new app in which I have to take care of design over mobile devices and tablets.I already read on SO that for this thing I need to create several buckets for sizes to avoid bad look of app on larger or smaller screen at the same time. here is the code I am working on

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="My App Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="32sp" />


    <!-- Email Label -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <!-- Password Label -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilLoginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/btnLogin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

]

***This is how the above code looks like on mobile phone (i.e Nexus 6)***

[image]

*****This is how the above code looks like on tablet (i.e Nexus 10)*** [image]

> **Notice that on tablet is looking so bad. I know how to handle design in different design buckets.  but I want to check if there is any
> other solution without replicating the same design file in different
> screen sizes buckets**

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Please have a look on this https://github.com/intuit/sdp it provides you different screen size dimensions using the SDP unit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of duplicate the layout try to:

- avoid to hardcode the dimension in the layout.
- use a `ConstraintLayout`
- use the different qualifiers

For example the margin in your root view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_layout_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_layout_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLogo"
            ..>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create different dimension in different folder:

**`res/values/dimens.xml`**:

```
<dimen name="login_layout_margin">35dp</dimen>
```

**`res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml`**:

```
<dimen name="login_layout_margin">350dp</dimen>
```

[image]

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Comment: @Gabreiele I know this method too. But this look not so much flexible. As we have to hit and trial the values. Like if  300 dp does not look good on tablet 10 inch we have to change it to 350dp 

also what about resolution will  "res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml:"  will handle resolution also along with device size?

Comment: @A.s.ALI It is just an example, there isn't a perfect rule that can work everywhere. You can use all the qualifiers to match your needs.

Comment: Can you please provide me the list of alternate resources name to support all devices and densities ??

Comment: @A.s.ALI Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

Comment: you are right by sharing that link. But I do not understand. If I have to make the layout out alternate resoulse like layout-large , layout-xlarge   Or should I go with layour-sw600dp 

which should I adopt? I just confused here.

Comment: @A.s.ALI Not so simple, it depends by the layout. You can also set a maxWidth in you widget (like the TextInputLayout) for example.

Comment: I think you are not getting about the confusion i have